# images not switch when click on color swatches in magento

Tags: magento-enterprise, color-swatches

When I click on colour swatches image is not changing. I do all the settings right. Colour swatches view with product but images is not changing. view this link.
[view problem](http://orderdedicatedservers.com/gifting/pankaj.html)

Please any one help me.

Comment: if this is duplicate question than you give me answer of that question.....give me your email if you have....or email me on pankaj@capsons.com for solution........

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Pankaj, you need to upload image on simple product, where simple product is created by configurable product.

For E.g: "PANKAJ" is a configurable product and Brown & Cherry is a simple product. So here you need to upload image to the Simple products.

Hope it resolves your issue.

Comment: i uploaded images in simple product but no result

Comment: any one please reply about this problem.......

Comment: i did all the setting correct as manual...my theme is supported color swatches...everything is working but only images are not changing....

Comment: color swatches not working product detail page and images not change also. http://superbuniforms.com/magento/special-deal/men-white-chef-coat.html